# Refreshing Data when dismissing Modal

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, segue

I have an reference to a managed object called `selectedItem`, I load the data in on view controller and have a modal segue (over current context) to another view to edit the **title property** of the `selectedItem`.

I expect a textLabel to refresh the data when dismissing the modal view but it does not. I have used the same method to add to the table data and it worked, because I use `tableView.reloadData` but how can I refresh the label data using the modal segue ? or basically have the label change to the new value.

**detailsViewController**

```
var selectedItem: Item!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    titleLabel.text = selectedItem.title

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    titleLabel.text = selectedItem.title
}
```

**EditViewController**

```
@IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {

selectedItem.title = editTitle.text

    var error: NSError?
    if context!.save(nil){}
    context?.save(&error)


self.presentingViewController?.viewWillAppear(true)
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});

}
```

PS: I tried to do a work around by using another segue to go back to the first view but that crashed, does anybody know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a NSNotification, they are pretty handy for this sort of thing, here's an example of some generic usage:

**Parent View Controller**

In viewDidLoad:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "udpateObject:", name: "udpateObject", object: nil)
```

In deinit:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "udpateObject", object: nil)
```

Then you'll make a func that matches the selector of the observer:

```
func udpateObject(notification: NSNotification) {

// here you'll get the object you update in a different view

    if let receivedObject = notification.object as? YOUR_OBJECT_DATA_TYPE {

        self.ThisInstanceVariable = receivedObject
        // Update any UI elements
    }
}
```

**Update View Controller**

Wherever you update your data:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("udpateObject", object: YOUR_UPDATED_OBJECT)
```